# Can you provide a custom shim/patch with zone.js?

Tags: javascript, zone, zone.js

The way that [zone.js](https://github.com/angular/zone.js/) works is by shimming out all standard browser/node APIs. That's a neat idea and seems to work quite well. It occurs to me that if its possible to provide your own custom shims then you could use that as a very flexible mocking system for tests rather than having to do stuff like rely on Sinon's fakeTimers.

Is doing this currently possible with zone?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, and `Sinon'sfakeTimers` are being `patched` in a PR of `zone.js` (not released yet), but of course, you can create your own `patch` with current `zone.js API`.

Comment: That's my question - what zonejs API do you use to for example use your own implementation of `setTimeout`

Comment: Looks like you're referring to [this PR](https://github.com/angular/zone.js/pull/1084)?

Comment: Yes, I remembered I did patch `fakeTimers`, if not, I will add the support to it later.

Comment: Do you think you can edit your question to show *how* to do it and then I'll accept the answer?